# javascript multiple AND conditions in IF statement inside for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I feel stupid because I´m stuck with a basic. I have three set of classes that contains paragraphs and I want to change the background color of each one depending on day (with New Dat.getDay().

I dont know how to mix for loop and if statements for each set of classes correctly. I guess it´s something simple but I missing it!

```
function changecolor() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getDay();
  var weekda = document.getElementsByClassName('weekdays');
  var sat = document.getElementsByClassName('saturday');
  var dom = document.getElementsByClassName('sun-fer');
  for (var i = 0; i < weekda.length && i < sat.length && i < dom.length; i++)
    if (n > 0 || n < 6) {
      weekda[i].setAttribute("style", "background-color:#0091ea;color:white;");
    }
  else if (n == 6) {
    sat[i].setAttribute("style", "background-color:#0091ea;color:white;");
  } else {
    dom[i].setAttribute("style", "background-color:#0091ea;color:white;");
  }
}
}
changecolor();
```

Comment: seems `n > 0 || n < 6` should be `n > 0 && n < 6` ... because **every** number is either greater than zero OR less than 6 (|| is OR, && is AND)

Comment: multiple for-loop terminating conditions looks like trouble

Comment: Thans so much @JaromandaX ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group conditions. Read more about [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

```
 for (var i = 0;( (i < weekda.length) && (i < sat.length) && (i < dom.length)); i++){
   // your code

 }
```

Comment: But...`<` already has higher precedence than `&&`, so what does adding parentheses change?

Comment: Good question. Is the answer that the parentheses make it easier for the human reader to visually parse the multiple condition (?)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem may be you have `background-color:#0091ea;color:white;` for all three options. Therefore you may not be seeing any change.

Personally I would break this up a little to make it more flexible and a little easier to read (and maintain). For example:

```
function changecolor() {
    var d = new Date();
    var e = null;
    var s = null;
    switch(d.getDay()) {
        case 6:
            e = document.getElementsByClassName('saturday');
            s = "background-color:#0091ea;color:white;";
            break;
        case 0:
            e = document.getElementsByClassName('sun-fer');
            s = "background-color:#0091ea;color:green;";
            break;
        default:
            e = document.getElementsByClassName('weekdays');
            s = "background-color:#0091ea;color:blue;";
    }
    // now update the color
    updateItem(e,s);
}

function updateItem(e,s) {
    var i, max = e.length;
    for(i=0;i<max;i++) {
        e[i].setAttribute("style",s);
    }
}
```